# Event on DataGrid row added, updated, observableCollection event?

Tags: events, datagrid, row, observablecollection

I have a class Seive that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. I have a ObservableCollection SeiveList.I input details of required Seive and dispaly those Seives in the dataGrid. SeiveList is the DataContext  of my dataGrid.

On each Seive added/updated, I got to perform certian calculations and display them. In Datarid, I can't find any event for row added or updated. I found SourceChanged event, but also is fired just once when the DataContext is set I guess, otherwise while the Seives are added/updated in SeiveList nothing is fired.

Which event do I handle that will help me know if any row is added or updated, so I can perform the calculations and  display the results on each change ? I came to know about CollectionChanged event of ObservableCollection, but also found that it doesn't work. More over, I don't have any class that implements ObservableCollection. How do I end up doing this ???

Any help is highly appreciated. Kindly try to help em at the earliest. Am stuck up with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution : I implemented CollectionChanged event of my ObservableCollection object, added the calculation to be done in it without pushing back the object that I changed yet the collection obj was changed. And this are workign perfectly fine.

Thanks